# Could adb command disable/turn off a display screen of android phone while it is still working as normal?

Tags: android, adb

I am wondering if adb command could disable/turn off a display screen of android phone while it is still working as normal.
I see the scrcpy tool (scrcpy -S) can do that it shows and allows interacting with a working screen of the phone on PC while disabling/turning off the screen of the physical phone.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found that there is no adb command for this.
Fortunately, thanks for guideline of scrcpy developer (@rom1v), I have successfully made it work with java code in instead.
https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/2888

Demo video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMXGYrTn11E